# Why am I getting NaN from this XIRR function?

Tags: javascript, xirr

This one is driving me up the wall.

UPDATE: Assembled in a jsfiddle that yields NaN: https://jsfiddle.net/eqcww2y7/6/

I'm using this XIRR function: https://gist.github.com/ghalimi/4669712

And into that function, I'm sending a simple pair of arrays - 4 dates, 4 cashflow values.

```
var dates = [
  "2016-01-01",
  "2016-02-01",
  "2016-03-01",
  "2016-04-01",
];

var values = [
  -1000000,
  0,
  0,
  750000
];

console.log('dates', dates);
console.log('values', values);
console.log(XIRR(values, dates, 0.1));
```

The function has a dependency on momentjs, which is not causing any issues - `console.log()` inside the function shows the dates are being parsed correctly.

That snippet above returns NaN, when it should return -0.68. If I run those exact same values through Excel:

[image: Testing XIRR in Excel]

Can anyone spot the issue? Is it with the function, am I sending the wrong values in?

Comment: Running the snippet: *"Uncaught ReferenceError: XIRR is not defined"* If you're going to make a runnable snippet, make it runnable. Otherwise just post a code block (but snippets done correctly are better).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, yes - just replaced it with a code block.

Comment: Check the values passed to `Math.pow()`. Should be the last line in [20.2.2.26 `Math.pow ( x, y )`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.pow): "_If x<0 and x is finite and y is finite and y is not an integer, the result is NaN_"

Comment: That seems to be the source of it, @Andreas, thanks! The x values eventually go negative, which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas got to the heart of it. This XIRR function was written in 2012, and as of ECMAScript 2015, Math.pow() behaves differently. I'm not sure if it's an issue that applies to all browsers/engines/implementations, but for my specific use case, XIRR() is returning NaN because the base and exponent inputs are going negative.

UPDATE: To clarify - in my use case, the base/exponent pairs start out like this:

```
x = 1.1, y = 0.0849
x = 1.1, y = 1.2493
```

But one iteration later I have this:

```
x = -0.512, y = 0.084
x = -0.512, y = 1.164
```

Since the x is a negative non-integer, I'm always gonna get NaN, no matter what the exponent is. At least that's my understanding of the limitations of Math.pow().

Comment: The base is negative and the exponent is not an integer ! `Math.pow(-1, -2)` won't return `NaN`

Comment: The problem is the base is negative and the exponent is decimal.

Comment: @wogan i have added a workaround in my answer found on the openoffice forums, which involves calculating an initial guess to provide to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the already given explanations, the XIRR function used in that gist mentions that

> Some algorithms have been ported from Apache OpenOffice

If you set up the same values/dates in OpenOffice Calc you get

[image]

---

Searching for this error in relation to XIRR in the openoffice forums you get to https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14006 where they mention that the likely problem is what we have identified here.

### <strike>Solution</strike>

They do offer a solution though (*turns out it was a solution to specific constraints*),

> I suggest that you use SUM(C4:C15)/C3 (*sum of the deposited values minus the received value*) as a guess

In your case that would be `SUM(B2:B4)/B1` and it indeed returns **-0.684592**

Comment: How is that possible? In that example, SUM(B2:B4) should be 750000, and 750000/-1000000 = -0.75. How do you get -0.68?

Comment: @wogan i mean that the XIRR returns -0.68.. when you pass the `SUM(B2:B4)/B1` as the guess parameter,  which is what excel also returns. So the formula should be `=XIRR(B1:B4;A1:A4;SUM(B2:B4)/B1)`

Comment: Just tested it by providing that calculated guess, but my function still failed, likely because on iteration 2 it again tried raising a negative non-integer base.

Comment: @Wogan It works in JS as well, see the updated script at https://jsfiddle.net/eqcww2y7/12/

Comment: And that works well, but when I plug in dates and values from the actual data I'm meant to get XIRR for, it crashes: https://jsfiddle.net/eqcww2y7/13/ . That pair of dates/values in Excel's XIRR gives me 6.46%, with a starting guess of 0.01.

Comment: @you are right. I do not really know what to use to make a good `guess`. I was only going by that example.